# How do I convert Javascript String into an Array?

Tags: javascript, html

This entire list is provided as a single String variable.

```
    instruments = '["guitar","bass","drums","keyboard"]';
```

How do I convert the String into an array so I can print each item out in its own individual div tag?

```
    for(var i=0;i<instruments.length;i++){
        document.write("<div>"+instruments[i]+"</div>");
        }
```

Comment: Whatever provides data in that format? It is valid syntax for a javascript array if only it wasnt in single quotes.

Comment: well it IS a javascript array, it is just initially provided as a String

Comment: @Jamiec: No. Doublequotes are correct inside the string. JSON is required to use them. The quotes that enclose the string do not matter at all. JavaScript treats `"` and `'` exactly the same.

Comment: @elusive. I know that, what I was saying is that without the outer quotes it *is* a javascript array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string contains a valid JSON array (like in your example) you could use `JSON.parse`, like this:

```
instrumentsString = '["guitar","bass","drums","keyboard"]';
instrumentsArray = JSON.parse(instrumentsString);
```

Do note that all browsers does not have the `JSON.parse`-function, so you might have to include an implementation. jQuery come with one for example and you can also use Douglas Crockfords json2.

Comment: of the two JSON.parse functions which one is preferable? jquery or json2.js

Comment: This is not really correct. A JSON parser will only parse a string that is valid JSON, a string can contain valid Javascript without being valid JSON. The string in the question is however also valid JSON.

Comment: Right. I'll modify the answer.

Comment: @eventhandler: I'm not sure if there's a difference in performance. It might even be that jQuery uses Crockfords implementation. It shouldn't really matter though. BUT, if you really care, you just have to test them and see which one performs better :)

Comment: @eventhandler: And of course, if you're not already using jQuery and just need the JSON-stuff, go with json2 since it does exactly what you want and nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you could actually use a [JSON parser](http://www.json.org/js.html):

```
JSON.parse('["guitar","bass","drums","keyboard"]');
// -> ["guitar", "bass", "drums", "keyboard"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your `instruments` variable:

Use `JSON.parse()` like so:

```
var instrumentsArray = JSON.parse(instruments);
```

Or, do something like this:

```
instruments = instruments.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/, "$1");
var instrumentsArray = instruments.split(/,/);
```

Then just use a `for` loop to loop through the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < instrumentsArray.length; i++) {
    // instrumentsArray[i] is the current element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the string list has any seperator then simply use split function.

Example:

```
var myString = "zero one two three four";

var mySplitResult = myString.split(" ");

for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
    document.write("<br /> Element " + i + " = " + mySplitResult[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eval it to get the array out.

```
var instruments = '["guitar","bass","drums","keyboard"]';
var instruments_array = eval(instruments);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do an `eval` on it

```
instruments = '["guitar","bass","drums","keyboard"]';
var instrumentsArray = eval(instruments);
```

then

```
for(var i=0;i<instrumentsArray.length;i++){
    document.write("<div>"+instrumentsArray[i]+"</div>");
    }
```